# C# Com E_NOINTERFACE Queryinterface

Tags: c#, com

I am sorry but I have to ask again. I am searching since many weeks and month for a solution now. 
The Problem is that have implemented a COM-Interface the throws only by calling a few methods an InvalidCast Exception E_NOINTERFACE and it tells me that I have to implement IUnknown.
So how can I do that?

I tried nearly everything...
Currently I have something like this

```
[ComImport,
 Guid("279AFA85-4981-11CE-A521-0020AF0BE560"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
 System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]

public interface IDirectSoundBuffer : IUnknown
{
```

...

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IUnknown
{
    void QueryInterface([In] ref Guid giid, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown, IidParameterIndex = 0)] out object ppvObject);
    [PreserveSig]
    uint AddRef();
    [PreserveSig]
    uint Release();
}
```

I really don t know what I could try more. I had on many different forums a topic discussing this but noboboy knows anything :(( pls help me.

Comment: Are you calling all the methods from your IUnknown Interface?

Comment: can you show the class that implements this interface?

Comment: I also want to implement QueryInterface on my own so that I can setup logging for it - did you get it running?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess (as it has been awhile):

Do not declare `IUnkown` and inherit your interface from it in your C# interop code. The [Com Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx) will implement it for you.

Comment: ok i ve got it. If i run it on MTAThread it works but on STAThread not